# Select data from HDFStore table based on value when column name is integer

Tags: python, select, pandas, hdfstore

I'm working with a `pandas.HDFStore` and I cannot find an explanation to something I want to do, i.e. use `select` method with a filter on value.

Here's what I want to achieve: I've got a `table` in my store, where the columns are string looking like integers, and I would like to be able to filter the values as written in the documentation:

```
store.select('dfq',where="A>0 or C>0")
```

My columns names are as follows:

```
In[28]: hs.select('/Data', stop=3).columns
Out[28]: 
Index(['2008', '2010', '2012', [...])
```

So, I just tried this:

```
In[29]: t = hs.select('/Data', stop=30, columns=['2008'], where='2008>0')
```

But I got the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bourgault_j\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-29-53380a428bf5>", line 1, in <module>
    t = hs.select('/Data', stop=30, columns=['2008'], where='2008>0')
  File "C:\Users\bourgault_j\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 669, in select
    return it.get_result()
  File "C:\Users\bourgault_j\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 1352, in get_result
    results = self.func(self.start, self.stop, where)
  File "C:\Users\bourgault_j\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 662, in func
    columns=columns, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bourgault_j\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3990, in read
    if not self.read_axes(where=where, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\bourgault_j\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3196, in read_axes
    self.selection = Selection(self, where=where, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\bourgault_j\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 4545, in __init__
    self.condition, self.filter = self.terms.evaluate()
  File "C:\Users\bourgault_j\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\pytables.py", line 580, in evaluate
    self.condition = self.terms.prune(ConditionBinOp)
  File "C:\Users\bourgault_j\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\pytables.py", line 118, in prune
    res = pr(left.value, right.value)
  File "C:\Users\bourgault_j\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\pytables.py", line 113, in pr
    encoding=self.encoding).evaluate()
  File "C:\Users\bourgault_j\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\pytables.py", line 317, in evaluate
    raise ValueError("query term is not valid [%s]" % self)
ValueError: query term is not valid [[Condition : [None]]]
```

I also tried with the following expression, but the result is the same:

```
hs.select('/Data', stop=30, columns=['2008'], where='"2008">0')
```

**Does anyone has a tip for me in this case?**

Note that I would prefer to keep these columns names, as they are used as keys in other parts of my code.

Additional note: I can already do cool stuff like this:

```
hs.select('/Data', columns=['2008'], where='index>"2015-10-19 14:49:00.01"')
```

Comment: Ok, first it seems that I forgot to use the `data_columns=` parameter for the `HDFStore.append()` call. But that still doesn't work for column names looking like integers, even when quoted.